# Django One to One - Don't want delete related model

Tags: django, one-to-one, relationships

So here is the problem. I got 2 models:

RefereeLevel and Referee

Here is both:

```
class RefereeLevel(models.Model):
    level = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=False,default=1,verbose_name=_("level"),unique=True)
    salary = models.DecimalField(blank=False,default=0.00,decimal_places=2,max_digits=4,verbose_name=_("salary"))

    def __unicode__(self):  # Python 2.7: def __unicode__(self):
        return self.level
```

And the second class:

```
 class Referee(models.Model):
    member = models.OneToOneField(Member,related_name='member',blank=False)
    information = models.ForeignKey(RefereeLevel,related_name='information',blank=False,null=True,default=1)
```

What happens now is that if I delete a RefereeLevel, the Referee with that level is deleted. But I don't want that, I want the Referee's information be set to none.

Is that possible?

Thanks,
Ara

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set the [on_delete](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete) parameter.

In your case :

```
information = models.ForeignKey(RefereeLevel,related_name='information',blank=False,null=True,default=1, on_delete=models.SET_NULL
```

Comment: Thanks didnt know you could that!

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to set on_delete param like

```
information = models.ForeignKey(RefereeLevel,related_name='information',blank=False,null=True,default=1, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

`on_delete=models.SET_NULL` will set the foreign key value to null

Comment: Thanks, I did not know you could that!